# Azure PowerShell Az module: generate bearer token for Databricks

Tags: azure-powershell

I need to generate token for Databricks usage (it will be used to generate Databricks token)

In Azure CLI `az account get-access-token --resource '2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d' --out tsv --query '[accessToken]'` worked perfectly well

I know that there's no alternative in Azure PowerShell Az module so I did research and found the following:

```
$context = Get-AzContext
$profile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
$profileClient = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient -ArgumentList ($profile)
$token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($context.Subscription.TenantId)
$token.AccessToken
```

It does work, but generated token has `https://management.core.windows.net/` claim instead of `2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d` required for Databricks

Any ideas how to run alternative to `az account get-access-token --resource '2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d'` in Azure PowerShell with Az module?

I have service principal with certificate auth protected by password and can't use az cli / python /etc, just Azure PowerShell Az module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call Azure Databricks REST API with Azure Powershell, please refer to the following script

```
$teantId
$subId="the id of the subscription which contains the databrick"
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription $subId -Tenant $teantId

$context= Get-AzContext

$resource="2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d"

$token = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account,
 $context.Environment, 
 $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), 
 $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, $resource).AccessToken

$groupName="the databrick resource group name"
$workSpaceName="the databrick workspace name"


$headers=@{
  "Authorization"= "Bearer " + $token;
  "X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id" = "/subscriptions/$($subId)/resourceGroups/$($groupName)/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/$($workSpaceName)"
}

$databricksInstance="" # such as adb-976301816870846.6.azuredatabricks.net
$url="https://$($databricksInstance)/api/2.0/clusters/list"

$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing
$result| ConvertTo-Json
```

For more details about how to call Azure Databricks REST API, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token#--use-an-azure-ad-access-token-to-access-the-databricks-rest-api)

Answer (score 2):

```
# ResourceId for Databricks
$resourceId="2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d"

# Get the Azure token
$tokenInfoFromAzure = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl $resourceId
```